# Compute the fourier transform of the function $\ f(x)=x^2e^{-x^2} $

Tags: fourier-analysis

So I have taken advantage of the Fourier Transform table $\ e^{-ax^2/2}$ $->$ $\ \left(\frac{\sqrt 2π}{a}\right)e^{-ω^2/2a} $

For $x^2$, I used twice from fourier table: $xf(x)$ $->$ $i\widehat{f}$'(ω)

Finally I got $\ (\sqrt πe^{{-ω^2/4}}(ω^2-2))$ divided by 4.

This doesnt quite fit the [wolframalpha calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2*e%5E(-x%5E2)%20fourier%20transform) of Fourier Transform, and I have to be missing out totally. Do I have to consider another constraint on the fourier table? Is this a convolution thing? Proper and stepwise help would be appreciated! And also, is f in the space $L^1(R)$?

Thanks!

Comment: * is equal with $\cdot$?

Comment: @Iuli come again?

Answer (score 0):

There are different definitions of the Fourier Transform yielding different results.

Type the integral directly into Wolfram Alpha and you will get your result, but divided by -4.

Comment: I see, can you explain what you mean by "different definitions of the f.t yielding different results" please?

Comment: Since I believe we are in the same class, you are probably using Folland's book. Look at the bottom of page 223. I believe that Wolfram Alpha uses one of those definitions (or maybe some other entirely!).